# ¿Cómo puedo contar los nodos dentro de diversos nodos hermanos utilizando Xpath?

Tags: xpath

Quiero contar dentro de los nodos servicios los doctores que tienen cada nodo, siendo estos nietos de servicios e hijos de médicos.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<!DOCTYPE hospital>
<hospital tipo="3" camas="1300" ciudad="Zafra">
<nombre>Hospital Catobe</nombre>
<lista_servicios>
<servicio planta="3">
<especialidad codigo="TX">Traumatología</especialidad>
<capacidad>20</capacidad>
<medicos>
<doctor clase="Jefe">
  <nombre>Juan</nombre><apellidos>Rama Pinto</apellidos>
</doctor>
<doctor clase="Interino">
 <nombre>Silvia</nombre><apellidos>Leal Tora</apellidos>
</doctor>
<doctor clase="R2">
  <nombre>Raquel</nombre><apellidos>Fuentes Lar</apellidos>
</doctor>
</medicos>
<lista_pacientes llena="N" dificultad="Media">
<paciente dni="11" nombre="Pedro" apellidos="Cano Rubio">
<gravedad>3</gravedad>
</paciente>
<paciente dni="88" nombre="Jaime" apellidos="Roda Toro">
<gravedad/>
</paciente>
</lista_pacientes>
</servicio>
<servicio planta="5">
<especialidad>Neurología</especialidad>
<capacidad>30</capacidad>
 <medicos>
  <doctor clase="Jefe">
  <nombre>Ana</nombre><apellidos>Palo Ras</apellidos>
</doctor>
<doctor clase="Interino">
<nombre>Manuel</nombre><apellidos>Mino Marrero</apellidos>
</doctor>
</medicos>
<lista_pacientes>
<paciente dni="22" nombre="Miguel" apellidos="Grajo Manzano">
<gravedad>1</gravedad>
</paciente>
<paciente dni="77" apellidos="Sora Burgos">
<gravedad>3</gravedad>
</paciente>
</lista_pacientes>
</servicio>
<servicio planta="7">
<especialidad codigo="OF">Oftalmología</especialidad>
<capacidad>24</capacidad>
<medicos>
<doctor clase="Jefe">
<nombre>Henar</nombre><apellidos>Vara Paz</apellidos>
</doctor>
<doctor clase="R2">
<nombre>Silvia</nombre><apellidos>Morales Ron</apellidos>
</doctor>
<doctor clase="Interino">
<nombre>Juan</nombre><apellidos>Abad Berra</apellidos>
</doctor>
</medicos>
<lista_pacientes llena="S" dificultad="Media">
<paciente dni="99" apellidos="Arroyo Cabral">
<gravedad>3</gravedad>
</paciente>
<paciente dni="55" nombre="Emilia" apellidos="Callejas Conde">
<gravedad>2</gravedad>
</paciente>
<paciente dni="33" nombre="Enrique" apellidos="Landa Seja">
<gravedad/>
</paciente>
</lista_pacientes>
</servicio>
</lista_servicios>
</hospital>
```

Comment: Y a parte de incluir el xml, que está muy bien, ¿has intentado algo?

Answer (score 1):

Entiendo que lo que buscas se obtiene con la siguiente expresión:

```
//servicio/count(.//doctor)
```

Resultado:

```
Int64='3'
Int64='2'
Int64='3'
```

**Nota**. Requiere XPath versión 2 o superior. He verificado que funciona en https://www.freeformatter.com/ Con versiones inferiores de XPath no es posible hacer lo que quieres con una expresión XPath. Necesitarías recuperar la lista de servicios con `"//servicios"` e iterar sobre cada uno de los nodos para hacer un `count(.//doctor)` en cada uno, e ir acumulando resultados. Es decir, necesitas programarlo y eso depende ya de qué lenguaje uses.